# Ruby Array sort_by value in variable

Tags: ruby

I would like to sort Ruby Array by key in variable, but I don't know how.

Situation

```
my_arr.sort_by {|record| [record.year]}
```

Will sort by a year of the record. But I want to sort by author, label, etc. And this sort type is stored in a variable like a String. So I need to evaluate the filter like

```
my_arr.sort_by {|record| [record."something_in_the_var"]}
```

Of course, I have fixed filters. But still figuring out how to do it properly.

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `send` does

```
str = "label"
arr.sort_by{|rec| rec.send(str) }
```

[send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__) is defined on BasicObject, so every object has it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
sort_by_this = "label"

my_arr.sort_by {|record| [record[sort_by_this]]}
```

Comment: I tried this, I got `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]'` :(